# MySQL: Get minimal set of entries where sum(value) is bigger then given number

Tags: mysql, select, sum, set

I've got a new/special problem where I wasnt able to get a good solution, maybe someone has an idea?

Table as follows:

```
|  id | value | 
---------------
|   … |     … |
|  11 |   500 |
|  12 |   300 |
|  13 |   200 |
|  14 |   400 |
|  15 |   300 |
---------------
```

Now I need to select (and then delete/update) these entries until my given value (1250) is reached, so after "the magic" I need the table as follows:

```
|  id | value |
---------------
|   … |     … |
|  11 |   450 |
---------------
```

Is there any good possibility to do it (performance matters)? (that select query, the other two should be much easier then)

I've found some solutions with subselect (w/o limit…) and "where sum() <= 1250" but they dont work, because they only select the ids 15,14,13&12, not 11. i need something like "give minimal set of entries where sum(value) is bigger then 1250 order by id desc"

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,value INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(10,700),
(11,500),
(12,300),
(13,200),
(14,400),
(15,300);
```

For simplicity, the following query assumes that ids are contiguous, but it can be easily extended to situations where they are not.

```
SELECT a.id
     , LEAST(a.value,a.value-i) value 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT *
            , @i:=@i-value i 
         FROM my_table
            , ( SELECT @i:=1250) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY id DESC
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id + 1
   AND a.value - i >= 0;

+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 10 |   700 |
| 11 |   450 |
+----+-------+
```